# How to convert TCVN string to Unicode string

Tags: c#

I have tried to convert TCVN string to Unicode string but no success. And this is my code which can support converting TCVN string to Unicode string:

```
class Converter
{
    private static char[] tcvnchars = {
    'µ', '¸', '¶', '·', '¹',
    '¨', '»', '¾', '¼', '½', 'Æ',
    '©', 'Ç', 'Ê', 'È', 'É', 'Ë',
    '®', 'Ì', 'Ð', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ñ',
    'ª', 'Ò', 'Õ', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Ö',
    '×', 'Ý', 'Ø', 'Ü', 'Þ',
    'ß', 'ã', 'á', 'â', 'ä',
    '«', 'å', 'è', 'æ', 'ç', 'é',
    '¬', 'ê', 'í', 'ë', 'ì', 'î',
    'ï', 'ó', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ô',
    '­', 'õ', 'ø', 'ö', '÷', 'ù',
    'ú', 'ý', 'û', 'ü', 'þ',
    '¡', '¢', '§', '£', '¤', '¥', '¦'
};

    private static char[] unichars = {
    'à', 'á', 'ả', 'ã', 'ạ',
    'ă', 'ằ', 'ắ', 'ẳ', 'ẵ', 'ặ',
    'â', 'ầ', 'ấ', 'ẩ', 'ẫ', 'ậ',
    'đ', 'è', 'é', 'ẻ', 'ẽ', 'ẹ',
    'ê', 'ề', 'ế', 'ể', 'ễ', 'ệ',
    'ì', 'í', 'ỉ', 'ĩ', 'ị',
    'ò', 'ó', 'ỏ', 'õ', 'ọ',
    'ô', 'ồ', 'ố', 'ổ', 'ỗ', 'ộ',
    'ơ', 'ờ', 'ớ', 'ở', 'ỡ', 'ợ',
    'ù', 'ú', 'ủ', 'ũ', 'ụ',
    'ư', 'ừ', 'ứ', 'ử', 'ữ', 'ự',
    'ỳ', 'ý', 'ỷ', 'ỹ', 'ỵ',
    'Ă', 'Â', 'Đ', 'Ê', 'Ô', 'Ơ', 'Ư'
};

    private static char[] convertTable;

    static Converter()
    {
        convertTable = new char[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            convertTable[i] = (char)i;
        for (int i = 0; i < tcvnchars.Length; i++)
            convertTable[tcvnchars[i]] = unichars[i];
    }

    public static string TCVN3ToUnicode(string value)
    {
        char[] chars = value.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            if (chars[i] < (char)256)
                chars[i] = convertTable[chars[i]];
        string rstr = new string(chars);
        return rstr;
    }
}
```

The code above is not reliable and it gives a wrong converting of TCVN string

**Explanation:**

I have tried to use the code above to convert TCVN string

- TCVN String: "C§  ngh̉ tØnh Bµ R̃a- Ṿng Tµu"
- Required result: "CĐ nghề tỉnh Bà Rịa - Vũng Tàu"
- Wrong result: "CĐ ngh̉ tỉnh Bà R̃a- Ṿng Tàu".

Example in code of calling function:

```
//Original string
var tcvnStr = "C§  ngh̉ tØnh Bµ R̃a- Ṿng Tµu";
var unicStr = Converter.TCVN3ToUnicode(tcvnStr);
//The result of unicStr should be "CĐ nghề tỉnh Bà Rịa - Vũng Tàu"
```

**Issue:** 
The code above give a wrong result of converting TCVN string to Unicode string.

**Requirement:**

I need your help to convert TCVN string to Unicode string.

Sincerely,
Dung Tri

Comment: Your code does a one-for-one character replacement, as you can see from the fact that the actual result string contains the same number of characters as the original.  Your required result has more characters than the original and cannot be achieved by simple replacement.

Comment: So the original TCVN charset has to convert into two or more characters to get the required result. Does MonoDevelop.Projects.Text.TextEncoding can help to encode TCVN string to Unicode string?

Comment: You may be able to find what you need in the source download for [UnicodeConverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unicodeconvert/)